# How to pronounce "in it" and "on it"?

Tags: pronunciation

Since these words are usually not stressed, people tend to speak fast and low and connected, I tried several times but still not sure about how to produce them.

Should "in it" be pronounced /ɪ.nɪt/ or /ɪn.nɪt/? I am sure they do put /n/ and /ɪ/ together.

And "on it" is /ɒ.nɪt/ or /ɒn.nɪt/?

Comment: If the *dot* in your pronunciations are supposed to represent some sort of a pause then the answer is neither. They are run together with no pause. /ɪnɪt/, /ɒnɪt/

Comment: @Jim Thanks! I am using the /./ because I am confused where the /n/ belongs. It's like they use /n/ in both in and it. Is it possible that people will add a /n/ just for convenience? Or it is actually just /ɪ nɪt/?

Comment: It's /ɪnɪt/ - you mustn't let the fact that they are two words graphologically affect your phonological transcription.

Comment: If you use /./ in IPA, it should be to indicate syllable boundaries.

Comment: Thank you guys! Your answers are all useful for me. How can I choose your answers to finish this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the /n/ from 'in' to join with the /ɪ/ from 'it'. It's probably most helpful to think of the syllables as /ɪ.nɪt/. This will make sure than the first /n/ joins with the following vowel.

Hope this helps!